# Uploading a image to picasa, using a byte array

Tags: java, google-app-engine, arrays, picasa

I have a byte[] of an image and I need to upload it as an image to picasa.
According to the documentation, an image is uploaded as follows.

```
MediaFileSource myMedia = new MediaFileSource(new File("lights.jpg"), "image/jpeg");
```

which means I need to create a File, out of the byte[].

The catch is, I have to do this without using FileOutputStream as it is not supported by Google App Engine (which is the environment I am using)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use MediaFileSource to upload a photo, you can use [MediaByteArraySource](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/media/MediaByteArraySource)  and pass it to photo.setMediaSource(...).